# Для меня(,) как учителя (,)это важно

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, будьте добры, следует ли выделять здесь обороты?

Для меня(,) как учителя(,) это важно.

Что для вас(,) как актера(,) все эти похвалы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) ***Для менЯ, как учИтеля, это важно.*** Значение причины, обычный вариант, два ударения.

Реже встречается другой случай: ***Для меня как учИтеля это важно***. Значение "в качестве", одно ударение.

Например: *Конечно, это важно для всех, но для меня как учИтеля это важно.*

(2) **Что для вАс, как актЁра, все эти похвалы?** Значение причины, два ударения.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Это  фраза обозначает примерно следующее: Что все эти похвалы для вас значат, если вы принадлежите к актерской среде?

Но тему в можно **дифференцировать** в конкретном разговоре, например: *Похвала приятна **всем**, а что для вас **как актера** похвала?*

В таком предложении оборот выделяется логическим ударением и не обособляется (значение "в качестве").